# How do I deploy Analysis Services Project via Octopus Deploy

Tags: deployment, ssas, octopus-deploy

I have an Analysis Services project setup in Visual Studio and I would now like to use Octopus Deploy to deploy it. The project has a .dwproj extension. I use TeamCity and would like to create deployment packages from there.

How do I create the nuget packages for Octopus from TeamCity (I don't think I can just add Octopack to the project).

Is there a Step Template available for deploying the Nuget Packages that would be created from TeamCity? In the Octopus Deploy community I have found a Step Template called "Deploy SSAS from Package", however, its not obvious whether this is what we should be using in our circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the project file (.dwproj) is just another MSBuild project and adding NuGet packages to this project through the Visual Studio context menu is not an option (the same goes for Database projects, e.g. *.sqlproj*), you could edit the project file manually and add the Import statement for the *OctoPack.targets* file.

```
<Import Project="..\..\..\packages\OctoPack.3.0.31\tools\OctoPack.targets" ...
```

As described in the post ['Octopack - should be able to be added to Database Projects'](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/1594).